# In one function, How to define one attribute of two elements

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#x').click(function() {
  var letter = 'X';
  alert(letter);
})
$('#y').click(function() {
  var letter = 'Y';
  alert(letter);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x'>X</div>
  <div id='y'>Y</div>
 </div>
```

In my script here, How can i define one of the letters when i click on one of them and alert in, While both in one function? something like this

```js
$('#x').click(function() {
  var letter = 'X';
})
$('#y').click(function() {
  var letter = 'Y';
})
alert(letter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x'>X</div>
  <div id='y'>Y</div>
</div>
```

I do realize that the variable letter isn't defined outside the function, But how can i merge the two function together and alert it once?

Comment: Can you reword exactly what you're asking for? Are you wanting the click event to be emitted once for either click or are you wanting the same function to handle the on click event for either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the clickable elements with a single handler - this is uaully done by adding a shared class to both - in this case ive just used what you have. Then use an attribute on each clicked element to distinguish - again I would usually use a `data-letter="X"` attribute but ive just used your Id.

```js
$('#div div').click(function() {
  var letter = this.id;
  alert(letter);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x'>X</div>
  <div id='y'>Y</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your selectors for your click event handlers with `$('#x, #y')` and then get the HTML from the clicked element with `this.innerHTML` and alert it (or `this.id` if you want to use that instead).

```js
$('#x, #y').click(function() {
  var letter = this.innerHTML;
  alert(letter);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x'>X</div>
  <div id='y'>Y</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3g6q8h59/

```js
$('div').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log("ID: " + $(this).attr('id'));
  console.log("InnerHTML: " + $(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x'>X</div>
  <div id='y'>Y</div>
</div>
```

I have used jQuery. Attached a clicked event to **div**.

Stopped the event propagation from the clicked **div**.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to do this:

**Get all divs inside the main div with id=div**

```
$('#div div').click(function() {
  var letter = this.innerHTML;
  alert(letter);
})
```

**Get specific divs by putting the requried div Ids as jquery selectors**

```
$('#x, #y').click(function() {
  var letter = this.innerHTML;
  alert(letter);
})
```

For simplicity you can **add custom class** (say 'needAlter') for all divs you want to process same way, and then use class name selector.

```
$('.needAlter').click(function() {
  var letter = this.innerHTML;
  alert(letter);
})
```

For this you also have to make changes in your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <div id='x' class='needAlter'>X</div>
  <div id='y' class='needAlter'>Y</div>
</div>
```